# Xampp object not found error windows version

Tags: xampp

After install the xampp, localhost/xampp is working fine.
But when create a folder, for example shirts4mike, and try to access by the link: localhost/xampp/shirts4mike **AND** localhost/shirts4mike
Both of them are not working.
Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your shirts4mike folder is inside of the htdocs folder, then try navigating to

```
http://localhost/shirts4mike
```